# Which eslint rule for infix spacing for class member?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

I am using TypeScript with eslint.

eslint can format the following snippet

```js
var a=2
```

to

```
var a = 2
```

But it does not work if variable `a` is a class member like this:

```js
class Hello {
  a=2
}
```

How can I config eslint so that it adds spacings around equal sign?

Comment: I think this problem is still not resolved here: https://github.com/babel/eslint-plugin-babel/issues/58

Comment: Look like eslint does not support this.
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/9516#issuecomment-339380128

Comment: There is a plugin proposal for eslint with a [class-property-space-infix-ops](https://github.com/peakchen90/eslint-plugin-proposal/blob/master/docs/rules/class-property-space-infix-ops.md) rule that seems to do it.

Comment: @TGrif that is what I want, thanks. Please post an answer then I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [plugin proposal](https://github.com/peakchen90/eslint-plugin-proposal) for eslint with a *class-property-space-infix-ops* rule that seems to do it:

> [class-property-space-infix-ops](https://github.com/peakchen90/eslint-plugin-proposal/blob/master/docs/rules/class-property-space-infix-ops.md) require or disallow spacing between operator '=' in class property